# Wordpress - Index Page Image Resizing

Tags: php, css, image, wordpress, scaling

I'm currently working on a blog for someone that has been designed by someone else. The design has the main index page listing articles from the blog. At the top of the design there are three buckets where the latest stories are and they all include an image from the article.

The images all have to appear at the same aspect ratio from the article when on the index page. Yet I cannot guarantee that the user of the blog (the article author) will take the time to make sure the image is the right aspect ratio to be scaled on the home page.

Does anyone know of any techniques to get around this issue?

It also needs to work across all browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TimThumb which can both resize and crop it to the right aspect. It is really good!

[timthumb - image crop zoom resize management](http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/)

Answer (score 0):

So, these boxes will display post's plus their featured images as thumbnails? Is that correct?

You could use the get thumbnail hook, and set the dimension in the functions.php file.

But it really depends on your currect code.

Are the boxes using a post loop?

An chance of showing the current index.php code.